# Reorder parts of a name with a suffix

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on vba code to reorder the parts of a name.  Sometimes there is a suffix (Jr, Sr, I, II, III, IV), and that is the part I can't figure out.  There is no list that I need to loop thru.  The elements of the name could look like this:     Johnson, Joseph Allen Jr
This code works for getting the last name moved to the end, but now I need to trim & move the suffix to the right after the last name.

```
Range("A1") = Trim(StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Range("A1")), ",")(0)) & " " _
                    & StrReverse(Split(StrReverse(Range("A1")), ",")(1)))
```

```
Result:   Joseph Allen Jr    Johnson
Result Required:  Joseph Allen Johnson Jr
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you cannot create a comprehensive list of the suffixes that you want to move, this will not be possible.  Excel cannot reason.  It has to be told what to do.

Comment: I assume that there are time there is no middle name or that there are 3 names instead of 2 or more.

Comment: Sorry so long to respond - Just getting back from a trip.The list of suffixes that come up in the data are: Jr, Sr, I, II, III, IV.  And, Yes good question, sometimes there is no suffix, and just 2 or 3 names.  The code I found is working when there are just 2 or 3 names with no suffix.

Answer (score 0):

So if your inputs are like Johnson, Joseph Allen Jr then you could set up an array/collection with the suffixes you want to check against. Then before you move the last name use

```
Dim i as Variant
Dim suffixArray as String()
Dim nameString as String
Dim suffixString as String
Dim arrayEntryLength as Long

suffixArray(0) = "Jr"
suffixArray(1) = "Sr"
suffixArray(2) = "I"
suffixArray(3) = "II"
...

for each i in suffixArray
    nameString = "Johnson, Joseph Allen Jr"    'or use Cells(1,"a").value
    arrayEntryLength = len(suffixArray(i))
    if Right(nameString, arrayEntryLength) = suffixArray(i) then
        suffixString = suffixArray(i)
        nameString = left(nameString, len(nameString)-arrayEntryLength)
    end if
next i

'move the last name of nameString

nameString = nameString & " " & suffixString

'rest of code
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. Really appreciate the code.   Getting a compile error: expected array at this line:  suffixArray(0) = "Jr". I'm really new at this and have tried several things unsuccessfully.  (Sorry it took so long for me to respond - was out of town last week.)

Comment: Just realized how to get through that problem - by adding this, which you were hinting - "Dim suffixArray(0 To 3) As String".  Now it stops running at "arrayEntryLength = Len(suffixArray(i))" with a type mismatch error.  Thanks again!

Comment: I realize my code has an error....it should be ```Dim suffixArry() as String``` so you don't have to set the number of entries the array can take. If you decide to add suffixes later then it won't matter, just add to the list. I'd also probably move the ```Next  i``` to after you've moved the last name and reset ```nameString``` and pasted that into another cell.

Answer (score 0):

The full name is a unparsed string and manipulating "Suffix" as mentioned above by Chris H may be a suitable way. Here is Fullname content model in Outlook contact Item: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.contactitem.fullname. Building an array of known suffixes will solve this in general. Watch out: the suffix may such as King Louis XVII, etc. is some historical context.